# How to validate the state of a java enum?

Tags: java

I would like to be able to validate the state of the enum to make sure there are no duplicate codes. For example consider the enum below.

```
public enum UniqueCodes {
    A(1), B(2), C(3), D(1);

    private final int value;

    static {
        UniqueCodes[] values = UniqueCodes.values();
        Map<Integer, Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (UniqueCodes code : values) {

            if (map.get(code.value) == null) {
                map.put(code.value, true);
            } else {
                String msg = String.format(
                        "%s enum contains a non unique code %s",
                        UniqueCodes.class.getName(), code.value);
                System.err.println(msg);

                try {
                    System.exit(-1);
                } catch(SecurityException e) {
                    System.err.println("Really Bad things are going to happen to the application");
                    // what can I do here to crash the JVM 
                }
            }

        }
    }

    private UniqueCodes(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Imagine the above enum with 100+ codes assigned and you want to make sure that no enum definition 
contains a duplicate value. If a duplicate value is detected I want to crash the JVM but that is not that is easy to do. Throwing an exception is not effective because a `catch(Throwable e)` will catch everything.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try { 
            System.out.println(UniqueCodes.A);
        } catch(Throwable e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Enum exception caught");
        }
    }
}
```

I can write a unit test to prove that the enum definition is good and there are no duplicate codes. But is there a way to kind of make it self testing and fool proof so that things don't run if the enum does not have unique codes?

Comment: `catch(Throwable e) {` **NEVER** do this!

Comment: @Doorknob `catch(Throwable e)` might very well be what an application server will do in its generic catch every exception handler. I want a way to fail the program if the enum has duplicates.

Comment: Okay, then `for(;;){}`? :P

Comment: @Doorknob won't the infite loop only lock up the thread that is running that code and the other threads can run.

Comment: Hmm, good point. Well I'm not sure this is possible if you don't have the necessary permissions (I was going to suggest JNI, but if you can't `System.exit`, you probably can't do that either)

Comment: I would use a `Set` rather than a `Map`. And the validation should be in a test, not in your production code -- if nothing else, it's cleaner and keeps your files more focused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of points:

1. It is simpler to use a set than a map for this.
2. Throwing an exception out of a class's static block **will** be effective because it will block the loading of the class. Even if you deliberately catch and ignore the first error with a `catch (Throwable t)`, any later code which tries to make any use of the "invalid" enum will spontaneously throw a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`.

I'd write the validation code as follows:

```
static {
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
    for (UniqueCodes code : values()) {
        if (!set.add(code.value)) {
            throw new RuntimeException(String.format(
                "%s enum contains a non unique code %s",
                UniqueCodes.class.getName(), code.value));
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. If you don't need any *particular* value for the unique codes, you should know that [Enum.ordinal()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal%28%29) exists, which returns the zero-based index of the constant in the order it was defined.

Comment: It should be more like `IllegalStateException` ?

Comment: @bsd Or perhaps `AssertionError`.

Answer (score 2):

It would be simplest to have the constructor check that the value is unique, like this:

```
A(1), B(2), C(3), D(1);
// Not initialized until after instances
private static Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
private final int value;
private UniqueCodes(int value) {
    // throws NPE
    if (!set.add(value))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Duplicate value: " + value);
    this.value = value;
}
```

but the challenge with enums is that static fields must appear after the instances, and so are not initialized until *after* all constructors are executed - too late, and you get a NPE when you go to use the set.

Fortunately, there's a work around!

You can use the [Initialization-on-demand holder idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom) to give you an initialized set *before* the instances are initialized:

```
public enum UniqueCodes {
    A(1), B(2), C(3), D(1);
    private static class Holder {
        static Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    }
    private final int value;
    private UniqueCodes(int value) {
        if (!Holder.set.add(value))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Duplicate value: " + value);
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

The reason this works is thanks to the class loader contract, which must initialize all static fields before the class can be used, and the class is loaded when first used. The Holder class is first used in the constructor, and at that point the class loader initializes the set.

To see what happens when you access the enum, see [this link](http://ideone.com/i5ECrv).

Comment: interesting approach with the holder strategy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is even worth doing for enums like your example.  Since you are hardcoding the enum yourself, can't you as the coder just make sure you aren't hardcoding the enum incorrectly?

Comment: Sure but I really want the codes to be unique and I don't want to check over 100+ codes I can always run a unit test to check but was just wondering If I can find a way that works without a unit test.

Comment: This is exactly the sort of thing that _should_ be handled by a unit test. Since enums are hard-coded, if the unit test passes, you know you're in the clear. I don't know why you would want JVM-crashing code in production to handle a case that should have been unit tested.